# MVC 5 openid connect on-premises ADFS 4.0 logout issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, adfs, openid-connect

I am trying to setup a new MVC 5 project and a new 2016 server with ADFS. I can authenticate with Oauth 2 and OpenID Connect. The issue I have is when I try to logout of the application. The sign out link points to the default /Account/SignOut action. When that action is called I get redirected to the post logout redirect uri which is https://website.com. This redirect loops until the browser errors out with "website redirected you too many times".

This is my signout method.

```
 public void SignOut()
    {
        string callbackUrl = Url.Action("SignOutCallback", "Account", routeValues: null, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);

        // Send an OpenID Connect sign-out request.
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = callbackUrl },
             OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType
            );

    }
```

If I just call

```
  HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)
```

the logout fails but at least the constant redirects don't happen.

Is there an overload of the Authentication.Signout() method which logs me out and then redirects to the post logout redirect uri?

Comment: This is just a comment to let you know you are not alone. I am investigating this issue myself. From what I have seen so far there does not seem to be a sign out endpoint in the "well known endpoints" on ADFS 2016 as there is with an Azure Active Directory.

Comment: Chuck, I'm still struggling with this but this site has a nice sample of how to setup the client even though it is for Azure. http://bitoftech.net/2016/08/31/integrate-azure-ad-b2c-asp-net-mvc-web-app/. It seem there is very limited information on the internet on how to setup on-premises single signon.

Comment: Thanks. I've done AAD single sign on using OID Connect. This is my first time on ADFS 2016. There is a sign out endpoint on the Azure well known endpoints, but doesn't seem to be the case on ADFS.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with MS support and determined that Sign Out is not currently supported for OID Connect with ADFS 2016. It may be part of a future release, but as of now there is no set release date for support.

Answer (score 0):

ADFS 4.0 (on Windows Server 2016) supports "Single log-out". If you use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIDConnect` package (this is the newer one, for ASP.NET Core) it works seamlessly.

If you query the well known endpoint for OpenID Connect configuration, which is https://your-server/adfs/.well-known/openid-configuration, you will find a key `end_session_endpoint` which contains the logout URL you should use.

Also, you can check the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/ad-fs-logout-openid-connect

For instance, in order to invoke it from your controller, you would would use an action method like this one:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult SignOut()
{
    var callbackUrl = Url.Action(nameof(SignedOut), "Account", values: null, protocol: Request.Scheme);
    return SignOut(
        new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = callbackUrl },
        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}
```

You might find this sample useful (even though it is for Azure ADFS, it works for local installs as well): https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore